# Keras regression model with 3 outputs gives accurate results only for one

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, regression

I am trying to run a neural network, using keras in python, which has as inputs 2 values and as outputs 3. The inputs represent natural frequencies, while the outputs represent equivalent ice load. The problem is after the model finishes its training, it seems that it is trained only for predicting one input and not all the three of them. The model is regression and not classification.Here i present my code

```
seed = 9
np.random.seed(seed)
# import dataset
dataset=np.loadtxt("Final_test_matrix_new_3_digits.csv", delimiter=",")
# Define dataset
Y=dataset[:, 0:3]
X=dataset[:, 3:5]
#Categorize data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.3, 
random_state = seed)
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=2,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
# compile the model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_logarithmic_error', optimizer='adam', 
metrics=['accuracy'])
# checkpoint
filepath="weights.best_12_8_8_neurons.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, 
save_best_only=True, mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
# fit the model
history=model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.1, epochs=100000, 
batch_size=10,callbacks=callbacks_list)
# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
print ("Accuracy: %.2f%%" %(scores[1]*100))
```

The accuracy of the model, according to python, is 65% but this fact does not deflect in the accuracy of the outputs, since the accuracy of the second output is lower than the first one and the accuracy of the third output is almost 0. The main target of the code to create a regression model where all the outputs will have the same accuracy.In the following the model accuracy, model loss and the predictions from each of the outputs respectively are shown:[image: Model loss]
[image: model accuracy]
[image: Output 1 prediction]
[image: Output 2 prediction]
[image: Output 3 prediction]

Comment: First thought that pops into my mind is unbalanced dataset ?

Comment: Can you define what exactly do you mean please?

Comment: If you have unequal score , it's either because your data is uneven , meaning that you have less training material for some features. Or that your loss function is unweighted, therefore not really caring about the other values. Try to look at your data to understand what is happening

Comment: You might also need to think about if your loss function is proper for all the labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Random Forests are more suited for your case. You should give it a try, specially if you have unbalanced classes.

As a workaround, you can increase the number of nodes in your `Dense(8)` layers , what will depend upon the variance of your data.

Then, you must check for minority classes and adapt the following code (Synthetic Minority Oversampling Technique):

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

sm = SMOTE()
x_train2, y_train2 = sm.fit_sample(X_train, Y_train)
```

Note that this code only works for binary outputs, so you should one-hot encode your 3 classes and apply it class 0 and class 1 then class 0 and class 2, removing doubled oversampling from class zero. Then you run your neural net model, increasing `validation_split` to 0.2.

Comment: Sorry but i cannot fully  understand how to do the one hot encode

Comment: pd.get_dummies(Y_train)

Comment: I still get the same results. Thank you very much though